# How to add a tablenote for a caption

Tags: tables, captions, tablenotes

How is it possible to make a table note for the table caption?

Something like

```
\begin{table}
...
\caption{...\tnote{1}.}
...
\begin{tablenotes}
   \item [1] : blabla.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
```

does not work in the sense, that no '1' is added after the caption to refer to the table note - which is written as expected.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Could you post a minimal working example?

Comment: Note that you do need to do this within the `threeparttable` environment. That seems to be missing from your code although it is, obviously, rather difficult to tell for sure given its incompleteness.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work fine, as [Bernard mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241848/how-to-add-a-tablenote-for-a-caption#comment575128_241848):

[image: table note in caption]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable,booktabs}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}
    \begin{threeparttable}
      \caption{\dots then\tnote{3}\dots.}
      \begin{tabular}{cc}
        \toprule
        a\tnote{1} & b\tnote{2}\\\midrule
        asdf;sd & asfjgso \\
        asdvn;szxc & qwetqwrnvwe\\
        \bottomrule
      \end{tabular}
      \begin{tablenotes}
        \item [1] : blabla.
        \item [2] : waffle.
        \item [3] : after.
      \end{tablenotes}
    \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Though obviously I wouldn't really put note 3 before note 1....